# Calc1 Optimization problem (solved?)

Tags: calculus

The problem says:

> Determine the dimensions of the rectangle of largest area that can be inscribed in a semicircle of radius $3$.

The answer of the sheet says: $h=(3\sqrt2)/2$, but I got $y= \sqrt{3/2}$

I'll attach [a pic](http://s24.postimg.org/arwws5fkl/image.jpg) of what I did. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to square the radius in $x^2 + y^2 = 9$.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2 + y^2 = 3^2$$

The equation has $r^2$ on the RHS.

**EDIT:**
Instead, try polar coordinates.

$$x = 3 \cos \theta$$
$$y = 3 \sin \theta$$

Here, our area is

$$A = 18 \sin \theta \cos \theta$$
$$= 9 \sin 2\theta$$
$$A' = 18 \cos 2 \theta$$

Our derivative is $0$ at $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$ and thus the dimensions of our rectangle are $$x = 3 \cos \frac{\pi}{4}$$
$$x, y = \frac{3 \sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Comment: Try polar coordinates for situations like these to minimize algebra

Comment: That's way easier, or shall I say faster? Haha